# Windows Security Center Service is missing

Tags: security, windows-7

I am trying to fix a Windows 7 machine here that has been infected with all kinds of Malware. I have removed all of them as far as I can see but I am stumped by one last task.

One little bugger managed to remove the Windows Security Center service from the list of Windows services. So I cannot start it or set to automatically start. At the moment I cannot get the Windows firewall to turn on or any anti-virus software.

The security center shows this when I try:

[image: Security center image]

Does anyone know how to add this back to the list of services so I may set it to start. I don't have a backup of the registry for this computer (it's not mine).

Many thanks

TT

Comment: This does not belong on stackoverflow. Try superuser instead.

Comment: Apologies. There are so many places to go for help that I get them mixed up. I tried Microsoft Answers once. A world of pain and ignorance was unleashed upon me. But now I'm here I would be grateful of any help. I will of course populate other boards with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never really be sure that you have removed all malware infections from a machine. There could be a myriad of registry keys/services that have been messed with.

My advise would be wipe it and reinstall Windows. This will undoubtedly fix your issues and you can then be sure you have removed the malware.

Comment: Yes - I think this is the path I'll be heading down. I just wondered if there was a way of adding back a missing service anyway.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. On several occasions I have spent hours trying to remove malware manually and patch up all the damage it has done, but you just end up finding more and more stuff to fix, it's much quicker just to go for a reinstall to start with.